# Distinguish between unit test build and debug build android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I'm using Android Studio v1.3.1 with Gradle 2.2.1. When running unit tests, there are some code that shouldn't be executed or should be ignored. 
Is there any flag that could be set for "**Testing**" that could be used in Java to check if a certain cod need to be evaluated?
Something like the following:

```
//Enable logging with roboelectric
tasks.withType(Test) {
systemProperty "robolectric.logging", "stdout"
}
```

In my app I need to execute a command to android system, but when I'm running tests I wanted to avoid the execution:

```
try {
 String command = "some command";
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"parameter", "otherparameter", command}, null);
        proc.waitFor();
 } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
...
}
```

This works fine, in my app, but when running test unit

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "parameter": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema nao conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado
```

I'm just looking for a way to avoid some steps,when performing unit tests, that don't related directley with what is being tested.

Comment: What code should be ignored and where is it? It would be helpful if you could post a short example of one of your typical unit tests.

Comment: The code to be ignored is in the Application class, is throws a null exception when running Test unit. The test unit is configured as Test Kind: class

Comment: Show us your code. You're trying to fix result but not the cause

Comment: Edited with some code added.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue in the meantime?